# Consulta php a mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda,

os doy un ejemplo, tengo una tabla con varios datos y en ella hay 6 celdas llamadas `piloto1, piloto2, piloto3, ...etc.`

> Se podría hacer una consulta para juntar las celdas en una y que me
>   printase todo en una misma celda de una tabla en HTML? Si es así, como
>   sería?

Un saludo

Comment: Tendrias que subir algo que hiciste para poder guiarte mejor y entender mejor tu consulta tal vez lo que buscas es un group_concat(nombre de campo) y te los trae a todos en una sola celda separados por una coma
Fijate este link tal vez es lo que necesites: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo de tu problema?

Comment: Si estas en oracle deberias hacer algo como esto... SELECT PILOTO1||' '||PILOTO2||' '||PILOTO3||' '||PILOTO3 FROM NOMBRE_TABLA y ya con esta consulta los pintas como en una sola columna, es una respuesta muy suelta dado que no se que herramienta uses para tu modelo de datos. espero te sirva...

Comment: es mysql....phpmyadmin.....

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero la pregunta dice que es mysql.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el **código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta**. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: **[Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Ivan, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] esto para que obtengas respuestas que ayuden en verdad a solucionar lo que preguntas, es muy importante, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que te refieres a imprimir todos los campos en uno solo, si es así solo tendrías que hacer la consulta respectiva, existe N formas pero acá te dejo una :

```
SELECT CONCAT(PILOTO,',',PILOTO_2,',',PILOTO_3) AS PILOTOS FROM TABLA
```

Después, solo guardariamos la información en una variable y lo mostrariamos en HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $variable; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score -2):

No se si entendi bien.

quieres imprimir una tabla, y en esa tabla una celda imprimir todos los campos de PILOTO.

si es asi primero tienes que hacer la consulta con php, y despues en una celda de html lo imprimes en una columna o renglon especifico